# Linux execute C Executable from PHP via Apache Webserver

Tags: php, c, linux, raspberry-pi, apache2

What I'm trying to achieve is to control the GPIO Pins of the Raspberry Pi via a local website from my Smartphone. For that I compiled two C files, one to set pin 17 to high, one to set pin 17 to low. In the screenshot below you can see the C Code. I can execute them in a terminal and the LED connected to pin 17 lights up, so it works.

But when I'm trying to execute the (compiled) file via PHP on an Apache2 Webserver using `shell_exec` / `system` / `exec` functions in PHP, it gives me a segmentation fault. I changed the owner of the directory where the file is located and the GPIO folder at `/sys/class/gpio` to www-data, which is the user the Apache2 Webserver is running as. But that doesn't work either. But a C program which writes to a txt file in the same folder as the program executable works without problems.

So I suspect that the problem is that I'm not able to chown the /sys/class/gpio directory to the Apache2 user. But I have no idea why or if that's really the reason. I tried to get this working for at least 10 hours now and it would make me very happy if someone could help me! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Instead post the code as formatted text.

Comment: You never check any IO function for success. That's a big NO GO! Do you have enough privileges to open those files?

Comment: "So I suspect that the problem is that I'm not able to chown the /sys/class/gpio directory to the Apache2 user" What happens when you try to check this? Who is owner of that folder and who is owner of the files inside that you want to open?

Comment: @Gerhardh, thanks for mentioning that, the files are owned by root. How can I change that, if sudo chown... is not working?

Comment: I am not 100% Linux guru... but according to your screenshot you only changed owner of the folder. You might need to add `-R` option to work recursive.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot go deeper into your system to debug or inspect it, but I can tell you how I solved the same issue on a similar embedded system.

I implemented a C++ daemon listening of a TCP socket (bound only to localhost for security reasons), running with root privileges, and accepting commands to manage the hardware peripherals.

The device exposes a PHP UI which manages the hardware by the TCP socket.

I hope it may be a solution for you too.